# Spinner does not animate when pulling down a list

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have a listview and the user should see an animated spinner when he is pulling down the list.

I use a SwipeRefreshLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayoutEvents"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/eventlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Keine anstehenden Veranstaltungen"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

onCreateView in my Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_fragment_layout, container, false);
    [...]
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeLayoutEvents);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    return view;
}
```

onRefresh:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    DataHolder dh = new DataHolder();
    dh.receiveData();
    allEvents = dh.getEvents();
    eventAdapter.setEvents(events);
    eventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

I get a spinner, but it is not animated. When I delete `swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);`, the spinner animates when the method is over.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

```
public void receiveData(){
    try {
        events = new XmlService().execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The XmlService is an AsyncTask.

Comment: It is all because you are blocking UI thread in onRefresh() ... calling .setRefreshing(true) and .setRefreshing(false) in the same method that is running on UI thread makes no sens ... the easy fix: move getting data to some background thread

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Unfortunately, it still does not work...

Comment: Indeed the error is that the `setRefreshing(false)` happens just after `setRefreshing(true)` so of course you don't see it. Plus that `receiveData()` is something that look a lot like blocking the UI Thread which is *bad bad bad*.

Comment: How can I create a background thread?

Comment: asked bazillion times ... move  dh.getEvents() to AsyncTask ... fire AsyncTask in onRefreash() set refresing state in proper method of AsyncTask ... Does dh.getEvents() use network? how you avoid the NetworkOnMainThread ... i bet that in the wrong way ...

Comment: `dh.receiveData();` uses network with an AsyncTask. `getEvents()` just returns a list.